# string " ' " issue when inserting into DB

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, special-characters

i am using sqlite client for windows phone for my database. I run into an issue regarding text formatting in this code :

```
cmd.CommandText = @" Insert into Restaurants (address,description,id,latitude,longitude,name,opening_hours,phone,sandwich,price,updated_at,website,score,rating_count,thumbnail_url) values ('" + r.address + "','" + r.description + "',"+r.id +","+r.latitude+","+r.longitude+",'"+r.name+"','"+r.opening_hours+"','"+r.phone+"','"+r.sandwich+"','"+r.price+"','"+r.updated_at+"','"+r.website+"',"+r.score+","+r.rating_count+",'"+r.thumbnail_url+"')";
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

The issue is that the text fields maybe like `"xyz it's abc"` and so the `'` breaks my update command. How can i keep the `'` and make my code run?

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: @amit not a good advice: while correct, it won't protect against SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Parameter` instead of hard coded string (query).

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into Restaurants 
    (address,description,id,latitude,longitude,name,opening_hours,
      phone,sandwich,price,updated_at,website,score,rating_count,thumbnail_url) 
  values 
    (@address,@description,@id,@latitude,@longitude,@name,@opening_hours,
      @phone,@sandwich,@price,@updated_at,@website,@score,
        @rating_count,@thumbnail_url)";
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a verbatim query string, which is (more) open to attack, use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param0", SqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = "value";
```

Comment: don't have Parameters, this sqlite implementation isn't an official one(windows phone doesn't support sqlite native)

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru Then AVD's answer is probably your alternative to this solution - you might still need some manual escaping however, to execute successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using stored procedures or parameterised queries rather than direct SQL. This will have the added benefit of making your code less susceptible to issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could escape the characters by doing something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Replace("'", "''");
```

But building a query the way you do could lead to some serious security risks. Have a look at [the following article](http://www.knowdotnet.com/articles/dynamicsqlparameters.html) which describes how to change dynamic sql to use sql parameters: